# Detecting Different Body Parts Using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I am trying to find different body parts (mostly upper-body parts) such as hands, chest and etc. I was wondering if OpenCV has any built in methods which could help. If the method could highlight the entire upper-body, it would be best. I am also trying to delete the person from the movie sequence and save him for further process. I would appreciate any helps since I don't have necessary train data to train my own classifiers.

Comment: Is there an appropriate stackexchange site for this question? I find this relevant to programming, though vague and maybe more appropriate for a Computer Vision stackexchange, as it invites some level of discussion. It is asking for libraries or methodologies, so maybe not a great question. How could it be rephrased to be less vague or more appropriate as a question?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a lot of experience with this, but I was looking into something like this and came across these papers and projects:

1. [2D articulated human pose estimation](http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/calvin/articulated_human_pose_estimation_code/)
2. [Deva Ramanan's Part-based models for ﬁnding people and estimating their pose](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~dramanan/papers/people_chapter.pdf)

I've tried the 1st, it's supplies Matlab code but the detection takes quite a bit of time and might not be suitable for realtime detection. Should be handy for an image sequence though.

Didn't get far with Deva's chapter but OpenCV has a [HoGDescriptor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html) ready.